# @Input in directive angular 6 not two way binding

Tags: angular, angular6

My custom directive `showError`, has an input :

```
@Input() isActive: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.isActive); // true
}
```

In `app.component.html` I use this directive (`isError = true` by default) :

```
<div appShowError [isActive]="isError"></div>
```

In then call a service and set `isError` to false in the callback.

But `isActive` in directive doesn't change value to `false`.

Comment: `But isActive in directive doesn't change value to false` where are you expecting it to be changed?

Comment: @yurzui : yep, i want it update value after call service.

Comment: Input is automatically updated if you didn't assign it to something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the changes in the `ngOnChanges` hook of Angular

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  // Here you can check changes in the `isError`
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-properties-change-detection?embed=1&file=src/main.ts)

Above is the forked working example of how change detection works in case of `@Input`

Comment: it's not necesary ngOnChanges or getter/setter in Input. You use getter/setter in input to give value to another variable, but the question is not about it

Comment: IMO OP is asking about how to update the value when there are some changes made in the variable

Comment: If the changes are made in "parent" you need'nt make anything. If the changes is made in "children", you need Output the change. Just in your stackblitz simply write: @ Input() name . The "names" change